# Proper $n$-coloring of a graph clarification

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

There exists a theorem that states:

*Let G be a planar graph. There exists a proper 6-coloring of G.*

Any single-vertex graph $T$ is a planar graph. However, $T$ surely cannot be colored using all six colors in any six-color set.

Is it then correct to conclude that a proper $n$-coloring only requires that **at most** $n$ colors are used?

Comment: actually the theorem states that even $4$ colors are enough.

Comment: There are theorems for 4, 5 and 6 colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. One is not required to use all $k$ colors in a $k$-coloring of a graph.